# How do Enzyme or Tokensets manage big amount of tokens (Solidity loops)?

Tags: solidity, tokens, out-of-gas, defi

There are 2 big project ([Enzyme](https://enzyme.finance/) and [Tokensets](https://www.tokensets.com/)) that allow user to create portfolios with big amounts of tokens.

You can add as much tokens as you want, always linked to a portfolio token that represents the share on the total invested money.

When you want to withdraw they should iterate each token and sell it to get the main token back to the user (sell all the tokens in the portfolio and get ETH or USDT). But that could lead to "out of gas" results.

I have been researching the [Github of Enzyme](https://github.com/enzymefinance/protocol) and the [Github of Tokensets](https://github.com/SetProtocol/set-protocol-v2) and I do not see clear how do they manage this operation. The use of loops could be obvious, but it could lead to "out of gas" errors. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have a sample transaction? It is always possible to do the withdrawal in several transactions.